# dropdown row on cgridview update on ajax

Tags: ajax, yii, cgridview

I followed this [post](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/29289-dropdownlist-in-cgridview/). But two things go wrong here.

1. The id is always targeted to the last id on the grid.
2. When cgridview is updated, i would need to refresh the page in order to update the next one (which is the last one, the incorrect row).

   ```
       array(
       'header'=>"Status Change",
       'type'=>'raw',
       'value'=>'CHtml::dropDownList($data->storeStatus->status, \'\',
           array(\'1\' => \'Active\', \'2\' => \'Inactive\',\'3\'=>\'Suspended\',\'4\'=>\'Pending\'),
           array(\'empty\' => \'Status\',\'\',
           "ajax"=>array(
           \'type\' => \'POST\',
           \'url\' => Yii::app()->controller->createUrl(\'ChangeStoreStatus\',array(\'id\'=>$data->store_id)),
           \'data\'=> "js:{store_status_id: $(this).val(),store_id: $data->store_id}", 
           \'success\'=> "function() {
                       $.fn.yiiGridView.update(\'inactive-store\');
               }",
           \'error\'=> "function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                   alert(thrownError);
                 }",
           )),
           array(\'class\'=>\'ChangeStoreStatus\')            
        )',
   ```

   ),

Answer (score 0):

You can use getter in your model

```
public function getStatusDropdown()
{
    $stats = array(
        '1' => 'Active', '2' => 'Inactive','3'=>'Suspended','4'=>'Pending'
    );
    return CHtml::dropDownlist('status',$this->status,$stats, array(
        'class'     => 'status',
        'data-id'   => $this->id,
    ));
}
```

So in your Grid you'll have

```
array(
    'name'  => 'Status',
    'type'  => 'raw',
    'value' => '$data->statusDropdown',
),
```

Now the trick to send ajax:

```
$url = $this->createUrl('ChangeStoreStatus');
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('initStatus',
    "$('select.status').on('change','body',function() {
        el = $(this);
        $.ajaxPost('$url', {status: el.val(), id: el.data('id')}
    });",
    CClientScript::POS_READY
);
```

Now you got your dropdown value and id of element in grid. Can be mistakes, but it's what you are looking for.